# Converting from Polar Basis to Cartesian Basis

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose a force $F$ is given in terms of its polar basis vectors i.e. 
$F = -2\theta e_r + 1 e_\theta + 0 e_\phi$ where $\phi$ is the polar angle and $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle. Furthermore, consider this force along the curve that goes from the north pole of a unit sphere to the south pole given by the parametrization: 
$r(t) = 1$, $\theta(t) = 2t$ and $\phi(t)= \frac{\pi}{2}$ where $0 \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I am looking to convert $F$ to its representation in the cartesian unit vectors. Is it correct to use the conversion formulas: 
$x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z=r\cos\theta$, where $r = -2\theta = -4t$, $\theta =1$ and $\phi = 0$? Then I could write $F = x e_i+y e_j + ze_k$?

I did this and get: 
$x = -4t\sin(1)$, $y=0$ and $z=-4t\cos(1)$. So it seems that this is not correct.

Comment: No, you're not correct about $F$. $F\neq xe_i+y e_j+z e_k$. You have to establish the relationship between the polar coordinate basis $e_r, e_{\theta}, e_{\phi}$ and the cartesian basis. What is true is that $e_r = xe_i+y e_j+z e_k$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Ah okay. So it seems that $e_\theta = \cos\theta\cos\phi e_i + \cos\theta\sin\phi e_j-\sin\theta e_z$ and $e_\phi = -\sin\phi e_i + \cos\phi e_j$. What is the intuition behind this? Do you have any hints on how to derive this?

Comment: It depends on the definitions of the coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$. You can derive them from the fact they have to be orthogonal on $e_r$ and normal. By the way, I made a little mistake in the previous comment, it is $re_r=xe_i+y e_j+z e_k$. If you want a more intuitive derivation, you have to go to differential geometry and study the relationship between vector bases and differentials.

Comment: @Raskolnikov So your hint tells me that $-2 \theta e_r = x e_i + y e_j + z e_k$. How can I continue so that I can find values for $x,y$ and $z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you figured out that $re_r = xe_i+y e_j+z e_k$, $e_\theta = \cos\theta\cos\phi e_i + \cos\theta\sin\phi e_j-\sin\theta e_k$, $e_\phi = -\sin\phi e_i + \cos\phi e_j$.

Moreover you also found $x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z=r\cos\theta$.

It therefore follows that

$$F = -2\theta (xe_i+y e_j+z e_k)/r + \cos\theta\cos\phi e_i + \cos\theta\sin\phi e_j-\sin\theta e_k $$

Filling in your requirement that $r(t)=1$, $\theta(t) = 2t$ and $\phi(t)= \frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$F = -4t (\sin(2t) e_j+\cos(2t) e_k) + \cos(2t) e_j-\sin(2t) e_k $$

or

$$F = (\cos(2t)-4t \sin(2t)) e_j + (-4t \cos(2t)-\sin(2t)) e_k \; . $$

Comment: Although I do believe the second term should $-4t\cos(2t)$? Other than that, thank you!

Comment: You are right, copying mistake. Thanks.